# How to convert a variable from an int into a template parameter only if it is convertable in c++

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I am trying to write a function that takes a variable of arbitrary type and sets it to an `int` value only if the type of the given variable can be converted to an `int`. My simplified code:

```
  template <typename T>
  void getInt(T& param)
  {
    int int_value = calculate_int_value();
    if(std::is_convertible_v<int, T>){
        param = static_cast<T>(int_value);  
    }
  }
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get errors such as

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(int&)'

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Which makes me think I can't just convert an `int` value of arbitrary type inside an `if` statement, which proves it convertibility. How do I achieve my goal? Did I miss something?

Comment: `if` -> `if constexpr`

Comment: In which library is `std::is_convertable_v<int, T>` defined?

Comment: @GeanSantos `<type_traits>`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::is_convertible_v` was added in C++17, if your code uses it then this means that your compiler support C++17, which also has `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr(std::is_convertible_v<int, T>){
    param = static_cast<T>(int_value);  
}
```

In a regular `if`, even if it always evaluates to `false`, whatever's in the `if` statement must still be valid C++. Even if the body of a regular `if` statement is never executed it still must compile as valid C++. Attempting to convert something to `int` when it is proven not to be convertible to an `int` will, of course, not work.

`if constexpr` makes it possible to do otherwise (as long as `if` itself is a compile-time constant expression). The body of the `if` statement must still be syntactically valid C++, but only syntactically valid.